# How do I calculate the area of a Brownian bridge movement model?

Tags: r, gps, kernel-density, adehabitathr

In the `adehabitatHR` package there is some sample code to calculate Brownian bridge movement model for a wild boar using the `kernelbb` function. I would like to calculate the area of the object that results. I'd also like to know the units of the area. I think NTF (Paris) / Lambert zone III", EPSG code 27573, is the CRS.

Here's the code:

```
require(adehabitatHR)

data(puechcirc)
x <- puechcirc[1]
x

lik <- liker(x, sig2 = 58, rangesig1 = c(1, 10))

tata <- kernelbb(x, sig1 = 6.23, sig2 = 58, grid = 50)
tata

image(tata)
plot(getverticeshr(tata, 95), add=TRUE, lwd=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getverticeshr` returns an object of class `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. You can use for example `gArea` from the `rgeos` package to calculate the area.

```
library(rgeos)
sp <- getverticeshr(tata, 95 )
gArea(sp)
## [1] 1576647
```

I assume that the units are m^2. To check the coordinate reference system (which was not set in this example) you would do: `proj4string(sp)`.